# How to disable code template in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, code-templates

For example when I insert `if` and a spacebar in front of a line, Delphi added the `then` and another line break after it. I find this very annoying and not helpful at all. I can type by myself without this kind of stupid help.

I looked everywhere in the Options, even deleted all of Code Templates but this still happens. And why I can't find any solution on the web? Am I the only one in this world to find this annoying?

EDIT: I've read that question five times already. I said removing the code templates does not work. And I am asking for **Delphi 7**, not Delphi xe3. I thought I made that clear.

Comment: Sounds like you've got an extra third party tool like gexperts or cnpack

Comment: Is this GExpert's feature? This was installed but I don't know where to turn it off.

Comment: This is a different question now

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate? I have the same problem and the referenced question does not handle the same problem than asked in this question.

Comment: @Alexander It is a duplicate as asked. However, the actual problem faced by the asker is not mentioned in the question. The asker's issue is with GExperts.

Comment: OK I found out it was Castalia, not GExperts. Thank you.

What should I do with this question?

Comment: @RedRomanov: Consider adding your solution as an answer to the linked duplicate, then deleting this question.